# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when i want to change a sliders value which is on a View which is not visible

Tags: xcode, ios6, exc-bad-access, uislider

I'm writing an App which can control the lights in the House.
I have a screen whith Labels and sliders for dimming the Light.
When another user changes the dim value it automaticaly puts my slider in right position.
But when I move to an other view in the App and I get notified that a dim-Value has changed I get an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,addresse=0x300000010)"-Error.

Sometimes it changes the value sucessfully, but at least at the second try it crashes with the Error mentioned above.

Hope anybody can help me!

Thanks
florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This typically means that the control on the not-visible view has been deallocated.  Instruments' Zombies template is the canonical way to track down which deallocated object is causing the error. You can find out more about using Instruments' Zombies template [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/instruments_help-memory-allocations-help/Eliminating_Messages_To_Deallocated_Objects/06_Eliminating_Messages_To_Deallocated_Objects.html).

In general, you could approach this by changing your app to retain all your app's views, even when they're not visible, but a better pattern would be for changes to the model to post an NSNotification, and have any visible, living views listen for that notification and update their state from the model when they receive it. (Note that on OSX you could use Cocoa Bindings for this, but I see that this is tagged with `UISlider`, and Cocoa Bindings aren't available on iOS.)

Comment: Thank you very much! NSNotification brought me to an running solution!